# E: Package 'mysql-client' has no installation candidate in php-fpm image build using docker compose

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Im fairly new to docker and so im trying to learn more about it using a laravel project, im following this tutorial:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-laravel-nginx-and-mysql-with-docker-compose

Ive adjusted the Dockerfile a bit from what the tutorial has but even the tutorial file causes the same result.

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/
# Install dependencies
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash - && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y mysql-client \
    

RUN npm install -g npm

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www
# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www
# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

But i keep getting the following error when i run `docker-compose up -d`:

```
E: Package 'mysql-client' has no installation candidate
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash - &&     apt-get update && apt-get install -y mysql-client     nodejs     build-essential     vim     git     curl' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Am i missing something?

I expected this to work since i am running `apt-get update` before installing `mysql-client`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 251, accepted):

php:7.3-fpm now use Debian 10 (Buster) as its [base image](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/ccbe53516fa2fd2d3b0ba680b83148b443a6ccf1/7.3/buster/fpm/Dockerfile) and Buster ships with MariaDB, so just replace `mysql-client` with `mariadb-client` should fix it.

Comment: Although I prefer `default-mysql-client` as given in another answer, still it is good to know that Debian uses `mariadb-client` and it is compatible with `mysql-client`.

Comment: As this is the first result when searching why it has no installation candidate (regardless of the php image), I prefer the other answer that isn't specific to that image.

Answer (score 269):

If you still want to use the mysql client, it's called `default-mysql-client` now.

Comment: I had this same issue on a Ruby Docker image and changing to `default-mysql-client` did the trick, thanks!

Comment: I am using PHP 7.2 and it fixed my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Fixed this for me on php:7.4-apache. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`php:7.2-apache` triggers the error as well, but I resolve it using `php:7.2.18-apache`

Answer (score -1):

it worked for me: `sudo apt-get update && apt-get install -y git curl libmcrypt-dev default-mysql-client`

or alternatively `apt-cache search mysql-server`
find out your servers then `sudo apt-get install default-mysql-server default-mysql-server-core mariadb-server-10.6  mariadb-server-core-10.6` 
in my case it was the above codes