# Laravel docker setup in ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I've been following [enter link description here][blog-post] by DigitalOcean on setting up laravel in docker within Laravel 18.04. When I run the command `docker-compose up -d`

I get the following error:

> E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libx/libx11/libx11-6_1.6.7-1_amd64.deb
>   Error reading from server - read (104: Connection reset by peer) [IP:
>   128.31.0.62 80]
>
> E: Failed to fetch
>   http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/j/javascript-common/javascript-common_11_all.deb
>   Error reading from server - read (104: Connection reset by peer) [IP:
>   128.31.0.62 80]
>
> E: Failed to fetch
>   http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/f/freetype/libfreetype6_2.9.1-3_amd64.deb
>   Error reading from server - read (104: Connection reset by peer) [IP:
>   128.31.0.62 80]
>
> E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with
>   --fix-missing?
>
> ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get
>   update && apt-get install -y     build-essential     mariadb-client
>   libpng-dev     libjpeg62-turbo-dev     libfreetype6-dev     locales
>   zip     jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle     vim     unzip     git 
>   curl' returned a non-zero code: 100

I've replaced `myysql-client` with `mariadb-client` following the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57048428/e-package-mysql-client-has-no-installation-candidate-in-php-fpm-image-build-u) from stack overflow as it was causing error of another kind.

It would be very helpful if anyone could guide me through this as I'm new to Docker.

```html
FROM php:7.3-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    mariadb-client \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Comment: It looks like a network issue `Connection reset by peer` is your internet working correctly normally?

Comment: If it is, there might be an issue with your docker network configuration. What version of docker compose are you running?

Comment: `Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d
` and `docker-compose version 1.21.2, build a133471
`

Comment: And there are no issues accessing those packages in your browser? For example, try downloading: `http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libx/libx11/libx11-6_1.6.7-1_amd64.deb`